# AttributeError when running Python

Tags: python

When running my program that makes the function call

```
self.getFileButton = Button(self,
                            text = "...",
                            command =
                            tkFileDialog.askopenfilename(mode="r+b", **self.file_opt))
```

I get the error

```
File "C:/Documents and Settings/l/My Documents/Python/csv_GUI.py", line 33, in create_widgets
tkFileDialog.askopenfilename(mode="r+b", **self.file_opt))
```

AttributeError: selectFile instance has no attribute 'file_opt'

Comment: Do you actually have a `file_opt` member?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you actually have a `file_opt` member defined in, e.g., your `__init__` method, or elsewhere?

If the problem is that you are defining one, but not until after you've done the `getFileButton`, can you just rearrange the order? If not, mgilson's solution is the right one. But otherwise, it's much simpler.

And if you don't have a `file_opt` member anywhere, it's even simpler: Don't try to pass something that doesn't exist.

Comment: rearranging the order will probably make this problem go away, but it will bring up a "strings aren't callable" error whenever you try to click the button.

Comment: @mgilson: That's true, although it's a separate problem. And if he doesn't actually have a `file_opt` member at all (which seems pretty likely), delaying the function call will just cause him to think he's solved the problem, until he gets the same error whenever he clicks the button. Better to find both problems right away.

Comment: It ended up I needed a file_opt file, I was just confused by the arguement in the function and thought it was something already defined in one of the libraries.

Comment: @user1876508: OK, keep in mind that, having solved this problem, you're very likely going to see mgilson's problem next, and he's already told you how to fix it.

Comment: My next question is, how do I access the file location as a string variable? I want to update the text in a label to display this information.

Comment: If f is the result of an open() call then use os.path.abspath(f.name)

Answer (score 7):

You probably want something like:

```
self.getFileButton = Button(self,
                            text = "...",
                            command = lambda: tkFileDialog.askopenfilename(mode="r+b", **self.file_opt))
```

The problem is that as you wrote it, the `askopenfilename` function gets run when the button is created (not when clicked).  Based on the AttributeError, you create the button before you create the `file_opt` mapping, but, assuming that the `file_opt` attribute exists when you click the button, this should defer that lookup (and function call) until an appropriate time.

Basically, `lambda` just creates a new function:

```
foo = lambda x : x*x
```

is equivalent* to:

```
 def foo(x):
     return x*x
```

Written this way, it's easy to see why we defer calling the `askopenfilename` function until the button actually gets clicked.

*There are a few cases where a lambda function behaves differently than a regular function, but we don't have to worry about those for the purposes of this post.

Comment: +1 for additional explanation on the lambda instead of just letting it lay there like so often happens in answers here.

Comment: It turns out this isn't his (direct) problem here, but as I said above, it seems very likely that this will be his next problem in about 15 minutes, so +1 for preemptively answering it.

Comment: @abarnert -- I did address the direct problem as well:  " Based on the AttributeError, you create the button before you create the file_opt mapping", but I didn't feature that prominently in my answer as you did, as I was assuming that the mapping was created somwhere close by.  Based on some of the other comments, it seems that assumption might have been incorrect.

Comment: Yeah, it sounds like he didn't have a `file_opt` at all, as I suspected. (Which raises the question of where he copied and pasted this code from…)

Answer (score 1):

I think that, generally speaking, you should avoid to pass arguments to the
callback function in the Button function itself (using lambdas), it's ugly and it's not
pythonic.

Do something like this instead:

```
def __init__(self, ...):
    ...
    Tkinter.Button(self, text='...', command=self.openfile).pack(...)
    ...

def openfile(self):
    return tkFileDialog.askopenfile(mode='r+b', **self.file_opt)
```

just to give the idea...

Comment: Admittedtly, I haven't spent a lot of time working with other people's python code (other than *lots of* SO answers).  However, if this isn't a candidate for `lambda`, I don't really know what is.  Why do you say that `lambda` is "unpythonic" here?  Defining an additional function clutters your namespace (which is unlikely to be a big deal).  Also, Your `openfile` function should not accept a `self` argument.  It'll get `self` from the closure and the button "command" receives no arguments.

Comment: @mgilson: It looks like he's defining the new function locally within this function, so the namespace issue is a non-issue. But you're still right that this seems like a place even Guido might use a `lambda`—in fact, most of the TkInter sample code either uses bound methods or `lambda`s.

Comment: Sure, this is a great candidate for `lambda`, but that `lambda` just make that line nearly unreadable to me. I'm not a big fan of `lambda` (and I'm not alone!), that's all. I'm a fan of `import this` ;). And sorry for the code, editing to make it clearer (I hope :P).

Comment: @abarnert -- Yeah, that's why I say that the namespace argument isn't a big deal.  Of course, you risk shadowing stuff in the global namespace, but ultimately, those things are only a nuisance -- not a real problem (which is why I said it is "unlikely to be a big deal").  My main point was that this is a classic place to use `lambda` and I'm not sure why it was described as "ugly" and "not pythonic" in this answer.

Comment: @NicolaLamacchia -- I can understand (and agree with you) if you're arguing from the standpoint that the line is getting too long.  It's probably over the 72 characters that PEP-8 recommends (or whatever the length of the line is supposed to be).  But, in this case, I don't think that the problem is with `lambda` *per se*.  If you imported that function under an easier name, the problem would go away.  I personally think that `lambda` is a *very* useful tool.  Consider having 50 buttons each with their own command.  using `lambda` quickly makes the code a lot nicer than explicit functions.

Comment: I also don't recommend creating a button and packing it all on one line.  Doing it that way, you lose your handle on the button and you need to go to great lengths to get it back.

Comment: If you look over the TkInter tutorial, reference, and other docs, most of the widgets are assigned to members of some object, and the callbacks are usually bound methods of the same object. And I think that's actually the best way to do things here for the OP's actual use case. But in cases where you are defining a quick throwaway widget (e.g., a confirmation dialog), a lambda seems perfectly reasonable. I agree that many uses of lambda (especially on SO) are unwarranted (e.g., `map(lambda x:x+1, foo)` instead of `(x+1 for x in foo)`), but I think this isn't such a case.

Comment: @mgilson: I usually don't do that, that's why I wrote "just to give the idea" ;) Anyway, I like to keep the code clean and more readable and I think this can be difficult sometimes when you use `lambda` a lot. A novice can tend to use `lambda` when it's not "necessary" and to not quickly understand the real behaviour of a `lambda` when he\she finds one (that's why I think it's matter of "Explicit is better than implicit"). I believe it's better not to get used to `lambda`, unless you can master the code readibility and the language itself, obviously.

Comment: @NicolaLamacchia: People who come to Python from functional languages, or sometimes from Javascript, definitely tend to overuse `lambda`. But people coming from perl, C/C++/Java, or ruby, or who are learning Python as their first language, usually don't have that problem.